# How to replace "

Tags: forms, post, input, replace

I want to post something in the database but whenever I put " I need to replace that with `&quot;` or `&#34;1`.

I have no idea how that works, any suggestions?

Comment: What programming language are you using to handle these requests? Consider adding that into your question tags too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just searched for [`HTML code for "`](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=HTML+code+for+%22&ia=answer) and got:

```
Encoded HTML Entity ("): &quot;
```

So replace your `"`s with `&quot`s.  To do this automatically with Javascript, you can do something like:

```
var postData = 'this is my " test " data';
postData = postData.replace('"','&quot'); //this is my &quot test &quot data
```

Comment: Yes, I know but is there a javascript etc. to automaticly replace the " symbols before adding it to the database.

Comment: Updated answer with Javascript's [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method.